# Excel 2007 macro fills to end of first sheet for all sheets in workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

The code below creates a new column (A), gives the it the header "Class" and then fills column A with the worksheet name until the last row of B for all worksheets in workbook.  It is working except that it fills all worksheets to the the last row of B from the first sheet processed for all subsequent sheets.  What have I done wrong? I like the fill to be determined by the last row of B for each sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddColumnFill()

Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    sht.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert xlShiftToRight
    sht.Cells(1, 1) = "Class"
    sht.Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value = sht.Name

Next sht

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddColumnFill()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With sht
            lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            .Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            .Cells(1, 1) = "Class"
            .Range("A2:A" & lRow).Value = .Name
        End With
    Next sht
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

`sht.Range("A2:A" & sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value = sht.Name`

Instead of

`sht.Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value = sht.Name`